# Good tutorials or good for using Core.Data in IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, ios7

I have been trying to use this [tutorial](http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-core-data-tutorial-with-example/).

But I want it to be saved in a thread other than the main thread. So far I cannot get the above tutorial working?

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160246/saving-in-core-data-with-context-crashing)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The best tutorials and documentation are the Apple's one :).

Core Data resource :

[Core Data complete documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

[Core Data Starting Point](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GettingStartedWithCoreData/index.html)

[Core Data Tutorial for iOS](http://class.ece.iastate.edu/cpre388/lecture/iPhoneCoreData01.pdf)

[Core Data Model Editor Help](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010379)

[Core Data Snippets](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008285)

Videos :

See the WWDC sessions, for example the 2013's sessions : 211.(Core Data Performance Optimization and Debugging) and 207. (What’s New in Core Data and iCloud)

Other tutorials :
[Many tutorials in Core Data here, cocoanetics](http://www.cocoanetics.com/)

And a special one aboute multithreading in Core Data ( how to use multiple context) [Core Data Multi-Context](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/)

Books :

Best book about Core Data, in my opinion, the Marcus S. Zarra's book.
[Core Data book](http://pragprog.com/book/mzcd2/core-data)

And also : [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord), A library that facilities the use and learning Core Data.

Comment: In April 2014 Apple updated the documentation and sample code. See "iCloud Programming Guide for Core Data" and others.

Comment: I helpful this tutorial...!!!