# What is the most proper way to save a small amount of data to disk in a iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the best way to persist a small amount of user data in iOS 7? Is it a hack to use `NSUserDefaults`? Is `CoreData` too heavy?

I am attempting to store a list of airports that a user finds useful. The airports are identified by `NSStrings` and have a small amount of data associated with them.

I am not opposed to creating a Core Data app, I'm wondering what the best approach to persisting a small amount of data.

Comment: Write the values to a plist file. Do some searching. You will find plenty of discussions on saving data in iOS.

Comment: As its array, you can simply write it to plist file. If you are holding the text in form of NSData, you can simply write it to file and read it as well. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)You can use plist files for saving the data by assigning the key value ,with help of the key we can get and save the value.[[How to use pList in iOS Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059966/how-to-use-plist-in-ios-programming][1]) which given by @harry
2)Or you can use NSUserDefaults for storing the value the small amount of data .[http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/quick-tips/storing-data-with-nsuserdefaults/]
3)Or you can use the sqlite3 for storing the Big amount of data .[http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app]
4)Or you can use core data for storing the big amount of data. 
[[Good tutorials or good for using Core.Data in IOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160935/good-tutorials-or-good-for-using-core-data-in-ios-7])

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 2):

`NSUserDefaults` is persisting to a .plist file stored locally in your app bundle so no it's not a hack. The only problem with `NSUserDefaults` is that it is not easy to store custom objects. The supported data types are `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`. If you need to store custom objects, Core Data is a better option but if you have just an array of strings and/or any of the above data types, then `NSUserDefaults` is the best way. It has a very simple API and is easy to manage.

Note: If you store an `NSArray` or an `NSDictionary` then any child objects also have to be of the above supported data types.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for using plist files for saving such kind of data. You can write a array of airports into plist file.

Here's the link showing how to use the plist files:
[How to use pList in iOS Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059966/how-to-use-plist-in-ios-programming)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're doing with the data. NSUserDefaults can hold a lot more data than most people lead on, and it is very easy to use. If you're not storing a crazy amount of data or fetching it from a database, I would use NSUserDefaults.